# Testcontainers could not find a valid Docker env

Tags: spring-boot, docker, testcontainers

Running testcontainers leads to failed initialization.
Config class:

```
  @ActiveProfiles("test")
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = {Postgres.Initializer.class})
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
@Sql("classpath: schema.sql")
public abstract class IntegrationTestConfig {
    @Autowired
    protected ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    @BeforeAll
    static void startContainer(){
        Postgres.CONTAINER.start();
    }
}
```

Initializer class:

```
@UtilityClass
public class Postgres {

    public static final PostgreSQLContainer CONTAINER = new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:14.0");

    public static class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            TestPropertyValues.of(
                    "spring.datasource.url=" + CONTAINER.getJdbcUrl(),
                    "spring.datasource.username=" + CONTAINER.getUsername(),
                    "spring.datasource.password=" + CONTAINER.getPassword()
            ).applyTo(applicationContext);
        }
    }
}
```

- ommiting simple test classes for brievety, I catch:

> Blockquoteork.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class */**/.IntegrationTestConfig]: class path resource [*/**/IntegrationTestConfigContext.groovy] does not exist
> 11:08:22.594 [Test worker] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [*/**/.IntegrationTestConfig]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
> 11:08:22.596 [Test worker] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [*/**/IntegrationTestConfig]: IntegrationTestConfig does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
> 11:08:22.825 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: file [/home/user/*/**/Application.class]
> 11:08:22.827 [Test worker] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Found @SpringBootConfiguration */**/Application for test class */**/RepositoryTest
> 11:08:22.983 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [*/**/tRepositoryTest]: using defaults.
> 11:08:22.984 [Test worker] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener]
> 11:08:22.994 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Skipping candidate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener] due to a missing dependency. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes and their required dependencies available. Offending class: [javax/servlet/ServletContext]
> 11:08:23.005 [Test worker] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@1f641fb7, org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener@69dc7b24, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@297454f7, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@602b7944, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@5f8d4b51, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@55821edf, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@5e5a2b74, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener@658098a2, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@50628080, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@155318b5, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@1add90e0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@7bf94e91, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener@3fdbb7ee, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@32c08610]
> 11:08:23.010 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - Before test class: context [DefaultTestContext@11939a9f testClass = RepositoryTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [ReactiveWebMergedContextConfiguration@229d508c testClass = RepositoryTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class */**/Application}', contextInitializerClasses = '*/**/Postgres$Initializer]', activeProfiles = '{test}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@1a10c47e, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@4816c0b, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@33e50ff2, [ImportsContextCustomizer@5e83298e key = [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@27261190, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@67d5ac2f, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@6029f2a4, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClientContextCustomizer@5bb97fe7, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@7e19755a], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
> 11:08:23.105 [Test worker] DEBUG org.testcontainers.utility.TestcontainersConfiguration - Testcontainers configuration overrides will be loaded from file:/home/user/.testcontainers.properties
> 11:08:23.140 [Test worker] WARN org.testcontainers.utility.TestcontainersConfiguration - Attempted to read Testcontainers configuration file at file:/home/user/.testcontainers.properties but the file was not found. Exception message: FileNotFoundException: /home/user/.testcontainers.properties (No such file or directory)
> 11:08:23.151 [Test worker] INFO org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerMachineClientProviderStrategy - docker-machine executable was not found on PATH ([/app/bin, /usr/bin])
> 11:08:23.151 [Test worker] DEBUG org.testcontainers.dockerclient.RootlessDockerClientProviderStrategy - $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is set but '/run/user/1000/docker.sock' does not exist.
> 11:08:23.152 [Test worker] DEBUG org.testcontainers.dockerclient.RootlessDockerClientProviderStrategy - '/home/user/.docker/run' does not exist.
> 11:08:23.220 [Test worker] DEBUG org.testcontainers.dockerclient.RootlessDockerClientProviderStrategy - '/run/user/1000/docker.sock' does not exist.
> 11:08:23.224 [Test worker] DEBUG org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception InvalidConfigurationException (Could not find unix domain socket). Root cause NoSuchFileException (/var/run/docker.sock)
> 11:08:23.224 [Test worker] ERROR org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please check configuration. Attempted configurations were:
> 11:08:23.224 [Test worker] ERROR org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy -     UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception InvalidConfigurationException (Could not find unix domain socket). Root cause NoSuchFileException (/var/run/docker.sock)
> 11:08:23.224 [Test worker] ERROR org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - As no valid configuration was found, execution cannot continue

---

I tried to switch tc versions: 1.16.2 \1,1.15.3 . I checked user privileges - I already start docker w/o sudo. I also checked postgres image - both 14.0 inside the docker and tc initializer. What else I could try to solve the problem?

Comment: UPD chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock didnt fix the issue. '' ''UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception InvalidConfigurationException (Could not find unix domain socket). Root cause NoSuchFileException (/var/run/docker.sock)''

Answer (score 0):

Well, Ive found out that java cant see files located into /var/run, so I remembered that I used flatpack for installation which turns out to be isolated environment for idea . Reinstalled traditionally idea works flawlessly.